# Not able to indexing to colunm in hbase table using phoenix

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix, bigdata

I have store 3 millions records in `hbase` table using `csv` bulk load and try to fetch some sql data using phoenix but I am getting more time to fetch records, So I have created index using phoenix but not able to insert index table record using phoenix map reduce process. I have used following command to insert indexing data.

I am not sure where this hfile store in `hdfs`. Please help me where this will store or something I did wrong then please help me for this.

```
sudo -u hdfs hbase org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.index.IndexTool --data-table BIGSS --index-table BIG_STATUS_INDEXS --output-path STATUS_HFILES
```

I have attached screenshot which mentioned error which I am facing. Please help for this.

[image]

I have used following link for reference.
 https://phoenix.apache.org/secondary_indexing.html